# Nested for loop eats up memory, how to optimize?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, multiprocessing, nested-loops

I have the following code trying to do some calculation in parallel using Python's multiprocessing

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

def prestart():
    ...

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=cores)

a_list = np.linspace(0.01, 0.1, 10)
b_list = np.linspace(0.01, 0.25, 10)
c_list = np.linspace(0.7, 1, 5)
d_list = np.linspace(0.01, 10, 10)
e_list = np.linspace(0.1, 0.3, 10)
f_list = np.linspace(0.7, 1, 5)
g_list = np.linspace(0.2, 0.9, 20)
h_list = np.linspace(0.01, 10, 10)
i_list = np.linspace(0.75, 1, 10)

for a in a_list:
    for b in b_list:
        for c in c_list:
            for d in d_list:
                for e in e_list:
                    for f in f_list:
                        for g g_list:
                            for h in h_list:
                                for i in i_list:
                                    pool.apply_async(prestart, (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i))

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

As you can see, those lists resulted in 500 million combinations and thus 500 million iterations in nested for-loops.

It looks Python will calculate all the combinations and save those combinations to memory while doing my calculation(memory eats up quickly and each CPU load fluctuate). If I minimize the total combination to few millions, everything went fine(memory usage stables at some point and all CPU loads stable at 90%).

How could I optimize the code?

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't blowing up your memory exponentially in prestart by storing the combination or something? At no point, should any part of the code that you've shown result in such behaviour.

What are you trying to achieve in prestart?

Comment: No, your nested `for` loops will specifically *avoid* having all 500M combinations produced at one time.  You'd do much better using `itertools.product` for that.  However, making that change is for iteration efficiency and readability; I doubt that the memory problem lies there.  Since you haven't given us the tools to reproduce the problem, we're not in much a position to help.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your nested for-loop keeping all the combinations around, that isn't happening. You are creating 500000000 python processes, each one will require something like 12000000 bytes of overhead... so you will require, *just for the interpreter overhead*, `12000000 *  500000000 * 1e-9 == 6000000.0` gigabytes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga, the problem is exactly as what described in the comment. Python tries to create 500M processes which consumes all the memory.

Following the comment, the solution is simple by moving `pool.close()` and `pool.join()` within the for-loop.

In my case, I move it under the `for b in b_list:` loop since I has 64G memory which has no problem in handling 5M processes